# How to add columns in csv file with Perl?

Tags: csv, perl

I have a csv file contains following data. Now I want to add some extra columns at the end. In these extra columns, they have different value, but each row content is same. How can we do this with Perl?

```
Original csv file
Item Price Number
A     11    2
B     10    3
C     20    1
...(many lines)
...
```

I want to add **retailer** and **buyer** information in the end

```
Output csv file

Item Price Number Retailer Buyer
A     11      2      Mike    Tom
B     21      1      Mike    Tom
C     30      4      Mike    Tom
...(many lines)
...
```

Each column has only 1 value, but it extends to the last row of csv file.
 (The column title and value can be hardcode, it's not the point)

Comment: Assuming the column separator is a single tab: Try this: `perl -F"\t" -anE 'next if $.==1; chomp @F; push @F, "Mike", "Tom"; say join "\t", @F' file.csv`

Comment: Need to add the header fields too... `perl -lane 'BEGIN{$,="\t"} if ($. == 1) { print @F, "Retailer", "Buyer" } else { print @F, "Mike", "Tom" }' file.tsv`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV 'csv';

my $rows = csv(in => *STDIN, encoding => 'UTF-8', auto_diag => 2,
  sep_char => "\t", keep_headers => \my @headers);

push @headers, 'Retailer', 'Buyer';
foreach my $row (@$rows) {
  $row->{Retailer} = 'Mike';
  $row->{Buyer} = 'Tom';
}

csv(in => $rows, out => *STDOUT, encoding => 'UTF-8', auto_diag => 2,
  sep_char => "\t", headers => \@headers);
```

Assuming your CSV file is actually single-tab-separated, and getting input on STDIN and printing to STDOUT.

Comment: Thank you. But I get following error message "Undefined subroutine &main::csv called at column.pl line 5." Is that mean I need to update my Perl module?

Comment: @1187Moonwalker: Did you explicitly import the subroutine as shown in the example code above - `use Text::CSV 'csv';`?

Answer (score 1):

Are they CSV files? I can't see any commas in your sample data. Perhaps they are tab-separated instead.

In any case, you don't need Text::CSV for this as you're just adding data to each line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if ($. == 1) { # first line
    say "$_\tRetailer\tBuyer";
  } else {
    say "$_\tMike\tTom";
  }
}
```

(If you really have CSV files, then replace the "\t"s in my code with ",")

This reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT` so (assuming it's in a file called `append_cols`) you would call it like this:

```
./append_cols < your_old_file.csv > some_new_file.csv
```